# How can I get count of nulls per database on a MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, metadata, stored-functions

I would like to get a count of nulls over all columns and tables for each database on a MySQL server. The result table should look like:

```
+---------------+------------+
| database_name | null_count |
+---------------+------------+
| database1     |          0 |
| database2     |       5643 |
| database3     |         72 |
+---------------+------------+
```

However, I wasn't able to get beyond count of nulls for a single table:

```
SELECT concat('select', group_concat(' count(*) - count(', column_name, ') '  SEPARATOR ' + '), 'from ', MAX(table_schema), '.', MAX(TABLE_NAME))
INTO @SQL
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'Accidents'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'nesreca';

PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Do you have some idea?

PS: I was able to get the result with MATLAB code. However, a solution within MySQL would be much preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are on the right track with dynamic SQL.  Because you want it for the entire database and not a single table, the structure of the query would be something like:

```
select table_schema, sum(cnt)
from (select "table_schema", count(*) as cnt from "table_name" where "column_name" is null union all
      . . .
     ) t
group by table_schema;
```

You can construct this as:

```
set group_concat_max_len=1500000;
set @subSQL = '(select "@table_schema" as table_schema, count(*) as cnt from `@table_schema`.`@table_name` where `@column_name` is null)';

select @subSQL := group_concat(replace(replace(replace(@subSQL, '@table_schema', table_schema
                                                      ), '@table_name', table_name
                                              ), '@column_name', column_name
                                      ) separator ' union all '
                              )
from information_schema.columns;

set @SQL = concat('select table_schema, sum(cnt) as NumNulls from (',
                  @subSQL,
                  ') t group by table_schema');

PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I should note that the default length for the intermediate value for `group_concat()` is probably too small for this query.  You will have to adjust it.  The system variable is `group_concat_max_len` (see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html)).